# Android gridView item width issue

Tags: android, gridview

I Created GridView with CheckedTextView as item.

Here my Gridview in XML

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip"                
    android:gravity="center"                       
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
```

Here GridView item in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:textColor="@color/gray_color"    
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle"/>
```

But it displaying two item in a row and each item displaying with extra space like below
[image]

how to avoid the extra space in each item in GridView ?

Comment: I also have same issue? How to reduce the horizontal space occupied by each grid item?

Answer (score 0):

try using match_parent in the item's width & height, not sure what was the problem but ive also encountered this one, tell me if this fixed it, otherwise ill look into my old projects and get you another solution

Comment: same problem even using match_parent in the item's width & height

Comment: check this android:stretchMode="none" into your gridView declaration

Comment: If using android:stretchMode="none" then gridview not appearing

Comment: Its working with android:columnWidth="40dip" but how to avoid 40dip hard coded value here.

Comment: put it in your values/dimens.xml

Comment: avoid constant value for android:columnWidth. columnWidth is based on populated text.